# What is the correct way to make a Queue class?

Tags: python, queue

The aim of this is to implement a queue class in Python.

1. Create a Queue class
2. Use it in Python and do the following: Queue, Dequeue, and Peek

The class Queue is written as follows:

```
    class Queue():

    def __init__(self):
        self.MAX = 30
        self.list = [''] * self.MAX
        self.FP = 0
        self.BP = 0

    def queue(self, item):
        if self.isFull() == False:
            self.list[self.FP] = item
            if self.FP == self.BP:
                self.FP += 1
            else:
                self.FP += 1
                self.BP += 1
            if self.FP == self.MAX:
                self.FP == 0
            elif self.BP == self.MAX:
                self.BP == 0
        else:
            print 'The queue is full.'

    def Dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty() == False:
            if self.FP == 1 and self.BP == 0:
                self.FP -= 1
            else:
                self.FP -= 1
                self.BP -= 1
            return self.list[self.SP]
        else:
            print 'The queue is empty.'

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.FP == self.BP:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isFull(self):
        if self.FP - self.BP == self.MAX:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def peek(self):
        print self.list
```

Then the code below is the main function:

```
    def main():
        choice = raw_input('Choose:\na - Queue\nb - Dequeue\nc - Peek\nResponse: ')
        a = Queue()
        if choice in ('a','A'):
            inputted = raw_input('Enter the data you want to add. ')
            Queue.queue(a, inputted)
        elif choice in ('b','B'):
            Queue.dequeue(a)
        elif choice in ('c','C'):
            Queue.peek(a)
```

However, when I try to run this using  **main()** , and using option a then peeking by running  **main()**  again, the list just contains  **[''] * 30**  and does not replace anything by the number inputted when you choose  option a. Why?

Comment: It's because a is local to main. It goes away as soon as main ends, and when you run it again the next time it's a new a.

Comment: thanks for the help